# How to check model column exist in cakephp2 or not?

Tags: cakephp, model

```
public function beforSave($option = array()) {
   if($this->columnName) {
      // Statement
   }
}
```

Something like that

```
if(!$this->loadModel($type)) {
   // Statement
}
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks!

Comment: I am using cakephp2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Get the model schema

```
$this->modelName->schema();
```

Check if my field is available or not

```
if (!empty($this->modelName->schema('date_created'))) {
    // statement
}
```

Or

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {  
   if ($this->hasField('date_created')) {
       $this->data[$this->alias]['date_created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. But I don't think you can use a function inside the PHP empty() function. You'll have to first get the results of the $this->modelName->schema('field_name') into a variable and then check if it is null or use the PHP empty() function on that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **getColumnType** and **array_key_exist**;

> getColumnTypes() Returns an associative array of field names and column
>   types.

```
 $fileds = $this->YourModelName->getColumnTypes();

 if(array_key_exists('columnName', $fileds)) {
    // Statement
 }
```

Comment: I also got the same approach. You were just few minutes late. Thanks